# Kendo Web v2012.3.1114 Breaks iPad touch support compared to version v2012.2.710

Tags: kendo-ui, panelbar

After transitioning from Kendo version v2012.2.710 to version v2012.3.1114, the touch-events on an ipad no longer trigger the navigation events for a PanelBar.

In addition I've noticed other kendo controls do not work for ipad after switching to the newer version.

To reproduce this error, I have created two identical websites simply utilizing different Kendo Web versions:

Kendo v2012.3.1114 http://kendo.mobnation.org/

Kendo v2012.2.710 http://kendo.mobnation.org/home/old

You can try both urls on an ipad and see that only v2012.2.710 triggers navigation (in this case a simple # change) when an item is clicked. You can simulate this in Google Chrome by enabling the developer console (F12), clicking the black gear icon in the bottom right corner, select the "Overrides" tab, change the User Agent to "iPad iOS 5" and tick the "Emulate touch events" checkbox (Ensure you refresh the page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install the latest internal build - few weeks after the official release (1114) many issues of this kind were troubleshooted.

Comment: Thanks! Just purchased KendoUI and as of version v2012.3.1304 there are no more iPad / iPhone / iOS issues that I can see. Cheers to Telerik!